# How to import a client certificate into Chrome on Google TV?

Tags: google-chrome, google-tv

We're looking to host a private web service in a cloud based server, and are considering client certificates as the method of identifying and authenticating authorized nodes.

Long story short, it seems that there's no interface anywhere to import such certs into the GTV Chrome browser.

I've found menu-> settings-> advanced settings->Under the Hood -> Manage Certificates, but the only thing that seems to allow you to do is revoke trust on manufacturer provided certs.

Although requiring users to install certs by hand is suboptimal, it seems to me that it should at least be possible.

Have I missed how to do this?

Furthermore, is there an API for this?  It might be better to have the users install an app that manages such issues, in addition to providing other services.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not something supported by the current generation of Google TVs. It is an edge case that would expose too much risk to the user and be a possible security hole if abused. Trust certificates can be installed by OEMs so it may be worth while to contact one of them.